# ajax call to php to return json doesn't work

Tags: ajax, json

So, i was search here for answer and this is really becoming weird thing, i allready worked with this and allways worked without any troubles, but now im having this trouble and i don't know whats problem. So, i hava ajax call like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin/update/update.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

and im calling this file:

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: application/json");
include "../system/functions.php";

$users = database::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated = 0 LIMIT 1");
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users);
print json_encode($user);
```

As you see im trying to put DATA into console log and see what im getting from response, but nothing is happening, also, when i check network on Chrome file is appearing with status 200 and application/json.

I have no clue what is problem.

SOLVED:

For some reason json_encode($user) doesn't want to return anything. On other side this one works good:

```
   $users = database::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated = 0 LIMIT 1");
   $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users);

   $user = array(
            "id" => $users['id']
        );

   echo json_encode($user);
```

Comment: What is the 200-reponse body look like?

Comment: It is, status 200 ok, type: application/json

Comment: Try debugging this with FireBug in FireFox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). In the console section you'll be able to see the ajax request fire and you can check if it actually is returning data. Also, is the destination url correct? You're using a path relative to the current page. If your current page is in a subdirectory, and 'admin' is a root folder, it may not use the correct path.

Comment: For example, when i echo $user['id'] and try to catch it with ajax call, it works, but when i change it to json like this, returns nothing, so path is good

Comment: The request has different parts, headers such as "Status" (Status: 200 OK) but it also has a "Message body" what is in this part is what the script returns, in your case the data variable. What does the message body contain?

Comment: message body is empty, nothing appears

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your database-query/database, you are returning null from mysqli_fetch_assoc or maybe the error is in functions.php, please provide more information

Comment: When i put invalid query then i get null in return, but when everything is valid i just get nothing in return.

Comment: Also success function in ajax object isn't triggered when im trying with json requests, but every other request pass and return something